# Java: I have a Set of custom classes. How to remove, modify, and re-insert one element of the Set?

Tags: java, set

I have a HashSet of custom objects.  I would like to remove one element from the Set, modify it, and put it back.  Is there any way to do this?  The issue with using `Set.remove(Object o)` is that it doesn't return the element I've removed.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;

public class Planet {
    private String name;
    private Set<String> moons = new HashSet<String>();

    public void addMoon(String name) { 
        moons.add(name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (obj == this) return true;
        if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) return false;
        Planet rhs = (Planet) obj;
        return new EqualsBuilder()
                .append(getName(), rhs.getName())
                .isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return new HashCodeBuilder(17,31).
                append(getName())
                .toHashCode();
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public Set<String> getMoons() { return moons; }


}

Set<Planet> solarSystem = new HashSet<Planet>();

Planet addThisPlanet = new Planet();
addThisPlanet.setName("Jupiter");
addThisPlanet.addMoon("Titan");

if (solarSystem.contains(addThisPlanet)) {
     Planet currentPlanet = // element of solarSystem that equals(addThisPlanet)
     // remove currentPlanet from solarSystem
     for(String moon: addThisPlanet.getMoons()) {
         currentPlanet.addMoon(moon);
     }
     solarSystem.add(currentPlanet);
} else {
     solarSystem.add(addThisPlanet);
}
```

Here what I'm doing is adding moons one by one (as they are "discovered") to existing (or new) planets.  If the planet isn't already in the set, it is added with its current set of known moons.  If the planet is already in the set, I want to remove it, add the newly discovered moons to its set of known moons, and then add the planet back to the set.

Comment: It seems to me that a `Map` would be more useful than a `Set` for what you want to do. You can have a `new HashMap<String, Planet>` where the map entry is the String planet name -> Planet object. Then you can `solarSystem.get("Jupiter").addMoon("Titan")` without creating an intermediate object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could deal with this by using a `Map` instead of a `Set` - add Planets to the Map if they aren't already there; add moons given the planet name.
The moons themselves stay a Set so attempts to add a moon again don't duplicate it.

I'm thinking something along these lines...

```
public class Planet {
    private final String name;
    private final Set<String> moons = new HashSet<String>();

    // notice I set the name in the Constructor instead of a setter
    public Planet(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addMoon(String name) { 
        moons.add(name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) { ...same as yours... }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { ...same as yours... }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public Set<String> getMoons() { return moons; }
}


// ... elsewhere ...

final Map<String,Planet> solarSystem = new HashMap<>();

public void addMoons(final String planet, final String... moons)
{
    Planet p = solarSystem.get(planet);
    if (p == null) {
        p = new Planet(planet);
        // add the Planet mapped by its name
        solarSystem.put(p.getName(), p);
    }
    for (final String moon : moons) {
        p.addMoon(moon);
    }
}
```

You could go further and make the SolarSystem an object itself, rather than a Map or a Set.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I had tried the `Map` approach before but one concern that came up for me is that I now essentially have two copies of the name, one being the Map key and the other being the object's `name` field, and that you have to take care to make sure these  are always the same, i.e., to ensure that `solarSystem.get(p.getName()).getName() == p.getName()` always.  I suppose I could do away with the `name` field and just rely on the Map key for that information...

Comment: @skrilmps That's why my sample code does `solarSystem.put(p.getName(), p);` -- it always uses the actual name. (BTW, `.getName() == p.getName()` is unlikely to be true, you need to use `.equals(p.getName())`)  — You need some way to get the object from either the Set or the Map, so you will have to be using the planet name outside the collection in any case. The main problem with the Set is that you need the _actual object_ as the "key" to retrieve the object from the set, and if you have that you don't need to retrieve it from the set, you already have it.

Answer (score 0):

The object you're hoping to get back from the Set *is* the object you already have, assuming you haven't changed it since it was added.  The `contains` method of `Set` uses the object's `equals` method to determine whether it is present.

See the API doco for `contains`:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily true.  As you see in my code for the `equals` method, there will be a match when the `name` fields of two objects of class `Planet` match.  However the rest of the fields could be different.  So they are not the same object.  And in fact my goal here is to take the two objects that have the same `name` and adjust them until everything else matches.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove and put it back to planet set. you can do it simply like this

```
    if(solarSystem.contains(addThisPlanet)) { 
     for(Planet currentPlanet : solarSystem ){
    if( currentPlanet.equals( addThisPlanet) )
{
 for(String moon: addThisPlanet.getMoons())
 { currentPlanet .addMoon(moon); } 

    break;
    }
    }else { solarSystem.add(addThisPlanet); }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I believe this solution would work, however you are essentially looping through every item in the set until you find the matching one, which will take O(N) time.  This same search is done for us by `HashSet`'s built-in functions `remove` and `contains` in O(1) time.  So in my mind doing it this way defeats the purpose of using a `Set`; putting aside the also desirable uniqueness of members, I might as well use a `List`.  However, this is a viable work-around for what seems like a major drawback of the `Set` class in that it doesn't return you a pointer to the removed object.

Comment: If it works for You , than you should accept and vote the answer , it will help other too